# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable when using a property

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, typeerror

Hope this hasn't already been answered out here.

When I try to print:

```
import gparser

gp = gparser.I_Parser() 
print(gp._z_matrix())
```

it's firing:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(gp._z_matrix())
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

In `gparser.py`, property `_z_matrix` is defined as such:

```
@property
def _z_matrix(self):
    coords = []
    p = re.compile('^ [a-zA-Z] +-?[0-9]')

    for line in self._file:
        m = p.match(line)

        if m:
            coords.append(line)

    return coords
```

I really don't understand how I'm causing this error to pop, can someone explain me this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties don't need to be called in order for them to execute. Simply accessing them (the dot `.` used) triggers the function attached.

In short, you're invoking the property `_z_matrix` via `gp._z_matrix` and then, after it has executed and returned a list (`coords`) as defined, you're calling the list object by using `()`.

Apart from the explanation, the solution is simply to remove `()` to avoid the `TypeError`.

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that!

Comment: That's fine @padrezulmiro, it takes a bit to understand properties and how they behave.

Answer (score 1):

You need not pass parenthesis to access a property. Just do `print(gp._z_matrix)`.